# Visual C++ find out max possible value of variable's data type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, rtti

I am using VS2010 to port an existing Mac application written in C++ to Windows. The following line of code:

```
T var_max;
var_max = std::numeric_limits<typeof(var_max)>::max();
```

given a variable, determines the maximum value for the data type of that variable. 
How do I write equivalent code in VC++? I tried using typeid to determine the data type, but it only gives out a string and cannot be used in a template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to determine the data type. It's T. Try this code:

```
#include <limits>
template <typename T>
T MaxValue()
{
    T var_max = (std::numeric_limits<T>::max)();
    return var_max;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int value = MaxValue<int>();
    return 0;
}
```